# OpenSuse Tumbleweed not upgrading the kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, opensuse

I've been upgrading my Tumbleweed machine using the following command:

`sudo zypper dup --no-allow-vendor-change`

(The no allow is to prevent codec packages from switching away from Packman.)

It's downloading and installing new versions of the kernel, but it does not use them at boot.

`sudo zypper se -s 'kernel*'` shows the following:

| Name | Version | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- |
| kernel-default | 6.3.6-1.1 | (System Packages) |
| kernel-default | 6.2.12-1.1 | (System Packages) |
| kernel-default | 6.3.7-1.2 | openSUSE-Tumbleweed-Oss |

However, opening the "About this System" dialog shows that the Kernel Version is 6.2.12-1.1 (this is the only option that presents in Grub).

Am I doing something wrong, or is there anyway to get a Latest Version boot option as well?
(I would still prefer for a last good version to also be an option.)

Sorry if this is an excessively stupid question, I'm still relatively new to Linux.

Comment: Is this an installed system (typically booted from an internal drive) or a live or persistent live system (typically booted from an external drive, e.g. a USB drive)? If installed, did you reboot after upgrading the kernel?

Comment: @sudodus, this is a machine with Tumbleweed installed, upon reboot the only option in Grub is 6.12.12-1.1.

Comment: When grub starts, you should be able to pick the latest kernel to ensure it works - within grub, hit the right arrow key on `advanced options for openSUSE Tumbeweed` and you should get a list of additional kernels. After that, running `yast2 bootloader` and choosing `bootloader options`, you should see `Default boot section` ensure it is set to `openSUSE Tumbleweed`